# AWS IAM policy to allow Cloudformation actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Originally asked on https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=825006#825006

I am trying to restrict certain actions to specific sources. For example, EC2 and Cloudformation should only be accessible from a certain source IP address. I am able to achieve this with the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": ["ec2:*", "cloudformation:*"],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": { "aws:SourceIp": ["1.2.3.4"] }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This works great (assuming there is an allow on ec2 and cloudformation without condition for the user) in that I can now create / view EC2 instances from source IP `1.2.3.4` but get errors trying from other sources.

However, if I try create a Cloudformation stack that contains an EC2 instance, the RunInstance action inherits my user account, but not my source IP. I would like to update the condition to allow Cloudformation source to be excluded from the `Deny`. I have tried this:

```
        "Condition": {
            "NotIpAddress": { "aws:SourceIp": ["1.2.3.4"] },
            "StringNotEquals": {"aws:SourceIp":"cloudformation.amazonaws.com" }
        }
    }
```

I have also tried 2 `Allow` statements on those actions, each statement only having 1 condition - `IpAddress` with the sourceIp and the 2nd allow statement with `"StringEquals" : {"aws:SourceIp":"cloudformation.amazonaws.com"}` to those actions. I still get an error when CloudFormation tries to execute RunInstances action.

Here's the CloudTrail event showing the failure:

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.05",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "AssumedRole",
        "principalId": "REDACTED",
        "arn": "REDACTED",
        "accountId": "REDACTED",
        "sessionContext": {
            "attributes": {
                "creationDate": "2018-01-19T07:47:40Z"
            },
            "sessionIssuer": {
                "type": "Role",
                "principalId": "REDACTED",
                "arn": "arn:aws:iam::REDACTED",
                "accountId": "REDACTED",
                "userName": "REDACTED"
            }
        },
        "invokedBy": "cloudformation.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "eventTime": "2018-01-19T08:10:39Z",
    "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "RunInstances",
    "awsRegion": "REDACTED",
    "sourceIPAddress": "cloudformation.amazonaws.com",
    "userAgent": "cloudformation.amazonaws.com",
    "errorCode": "Client.UnauthorizedOperation",
    "errorMessage": "You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: REDACTED",
    "requestParameters": { <details of instance here> },
    "responseElements": null,
    "requestID": "REDACTED",
    "eventID": "REDACTED",
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "recipientAccountId": "REDACTED"
}
```

I have tried string matches on `aws:SourceIp`, `aws:SourceIpAddress`, `aws:UserAgent` - How can I allow ec2 actions to cloudformation?

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting challange. 

What if you evaluate both in a single line with StringNotEquals maybe?

`"Condition": {
            "NotIpAddress": { "aws:SourceIp": ["1.2.3.4"] },
            "StringNotEquals": {"aws:SourceIp":"cloudformation.amazonaws.com" }
        }
    }`

Comment: I believe I did try that. The internals of matching the sourceIp to cloudformation.amazonaws.com seemed to break. Not sure what fields would be available for the condition...

Comment: @Brett did you find the solution? i am experiencing same issue

Comment: @Brett Did you figure this one out? `aws:SourceIp":"cloudformation.amazonaws.com"` is actually just how it's shown in CloudTrail, AWS replaces the actual IP address with the service URL, but the IAM is evaluated with an actual IP address, not with a URL.